# How to reset the preferences to default values when using fragments

Tags: android, android-fragments, sharedpreferences, fragment, preferences

I had function to reset preferences

it looked like this

```
Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.clear();
editor.commit();
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Prefs.this, R.xml.preferences, true);
```

now I can clear the settings with editor.clear(); But I do not know how to set the default values , because I do not have one preferences.xml file, I started to use headers and preferences fragment like this http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings.html#Fragment and I do not have one preferences.xml file ,I have 3 files for each fragment...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you're using fragments as the method of displaying preferences. Maybe because you're using two-pane preferences layout. However, this only means that you *display* them that way.

Yes, you have 3 XML files, each containing preferences for each fragment. But you could have such 3 files even if you haven't used fragments. Suppose your preference files are named `R.xml.pref1`, `R.xml.pref2` and `R.xml.pref3`. You reset preferences just like before, you just have to do that for each preference file. So, simply call:

```
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Prefs.this, R.xml.pref1, true);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Prefs.this, R.xml.pref2, true);
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(Prefs.this, R.xml.pref3, true);
```

And you're done. Of course, you could reset just the preferences from a particular file.